# Clear cookies or logout so the next scenario is not logged in

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber

How to Clear cookies after the test so the next test I run is not already logged in. I am trying to test logins and the solution below i am trying does not work. It feels this is the cucumber issue?

```
var myHooks = function () {
        // Synchronous
        this.Before(function (scenario) {
          this.count = 0;
          return this.driver.open();
        });

        // Asynchronous Callback
        this.Before(function (scenario, callback) {
          var world = this;
          tmp.dir({unsafeCleanup: true}, function(error, dir) {
            if (error) {
              callback(error);
            } else {
              world.tmpDir = dir;
              callback();
            }
          });
        });

        // Asynchronous Promise
        this.After(function (scenario) {
          // Assuming this.driver is a selenium webdriver
        return this.driver.close();
        });
      };

      module.exports = myHooks;
```

I also tried to change the config file and added shardTestFiles: true but no luck. What can i add in the config file so it restarts the browser after each cucumber scenario? Note that i am adding multiple examples in the feature file for login

```
const crew = require('serenity-js/lib/stage_crew');

exports.config = {
  getPageTimeout: 30000,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  baseUrl: 'https://abcccc.com/',
  specs: [ 'features/**/*.feature' ],
  shardTestFiles: true,
  multicapabilities: [{
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  /* }, {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
  }, {
    'browserName': 'internet explorer' */
  }],

  // maxSession: 2,

  framework: 'custom',

  frameworkPath: require.resolve('serenity-js'),

  serenity: {
    crew: [
      crew.serenityBDDReporter(),
      crew.photographer(),
      crew.consoleReporter()
    ]
  },

  cucumberOpts: {
    require: [ './features/step_definition/*.ts' ],
    format: [ "pretty" ],
    compiler: 'ts:ts-node/register'
  }
};
```

And here is my feature file, it seems like this might be a cucumber issue?

```
Feature: Add item and place the order for that item
    In order to wear something new
    As an online shopping customer
    I want to be able to add an item to my shopping bag and then place the order

    Scenario Outline: Add an item to shopping bag to place the order using PaypalPro
        Given "<User>" is logged in to his "<EnvName>" account
         When he searches item with SKU "<SKUID>" from "<Gender>" section and adds it to his shopping bag
         Then "<User>" can place the order
    Examples:
        | User         | EnvName | SKUID        | Gender |
        | user1        | Test  | 51230M000010   | men    |
        | user2        | Test  | 51230M000010   | women  |
```

Comment: One possible option, update your config and add `shardTestFiles: true` to `capabilities`.  After every test, the browser will close and the next test will start a new session.

Comment: i tried but it does not work. I have updated my code

Comment: Is it just 1 feature file? In order for the browser to "reset", it has to be running distinct tests from different files.